# Accessing a WCF-service using Java

Tags: java, .net, wcf, protocols, protocol-buffers

I'm developing a web-service using WCF, which I want to access using a client written in Java. I will encode the messages using Protocol Buffers (with Marc Gravell's [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) to be exact).

Is this possible to achive or must the client be written in .NET as well? I know that data serialized with Protocol Buffers is binary interopable but I don't know if WCF adds any platform-specific meta-data on top of the encoded protocol-messages.

I don't care if the WCF-service is RESTful, SOAP-based or whatever other forms WCF-support, I just want the actual payload to be encoded using PB. Is this possible and if it is, I would very much appreciate a brief example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you program your WCF service to take a byte array, you can stuff whatever you want in there, like a protobuf message.Could be as simple as

```
  [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMessageService{
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void SendMessage(byte[] msg);
    }

  [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
   public class MessageService: IMessageService{

        public void SendMessage(byte[] msg) {
          //decode the protobuf msg and deal with it.
        }

    }
```

Configure the WCF endpoint as SOAP, then talking to that from
Java should be straight forward. Whether WCF/Soap would be overkill for this is another matter, iirc protobuf comes with its own framework for simple RPC.

Comment: Thanks, that's an option. I'd prefer though if I could actually separate it into several methods, otheriwse I'd sort of lose the point of using WCF.

Answer (score -1):

I have never used protobuf-net but interop was the whole point.

> platform independent - portable between different programming architectures